# Error al crear bd postgres con prisma : P1001: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5432`

Tags: nodejs, base-de-datos, express

actualmente me encuentro trabajando EN WINDOWS con nodejs, prisma y express y cuando quiero ejecutar npx prisma migrate dev para levantar la bbdd recibo el error:

*Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5432`

Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`5432`.*

Tengo postgresql 14 instalado en mi ordenador y tengo pgadmin, he intentado de todo, hasta borrar postgres y volverlo a instalar pero nada de eso lo soluciona

Desde Services he chequeado que postgres tiene status = Running, incluso con otras tecnolgías como  Django o python no tengo problemas con postgres por lo que sospecho que debe haber algun problema con prisma o node.

Version de node : 16.16.0

variable database_url de mi archivo .env:
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:1234@localhost:5432/db_test

ACLARACIÓN: POSTGRESQL ESTA CORRIENDO EN EL PUERTO 5432[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Falta ver que en el archivo `postgresql.conf` el parámetro `listen_address` esté con valor `*` para que escuche por todas las interfaces y no sólo por IPv6 o por localhost... lo otro, falta ver cómo está el `pg_hba.conf`

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por su pronta respuesta, revisé el archivo postgresql.conf y en el parámetro listen_address esta de la siguiente manera:
listen_addresses = '*', en cuanto al archivo pg_hba.conf, que es importante allí para revisar?